# Julia - pipe to Julia REPL

Tags: pipe, julia, named-pipes, read-eval-print-loop

Can I pipe terminal input to a running Julia REPL?

In a terminal I might create a pipe

```
mkfifo juliapipe
```

Inside the Julia REPL I've tried

```
connect("juliapipe")
```

which returns the error

```
ERROR: connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
```

Is there a way to do this? Either with named pipes or any other way

Comment: Doing a loop around `eval(parse(readline(f)))` should basically execute statements from `f`, which can be a named pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Like @DanGetz suggested, one approach would be to `display(eval(parse(f)))` until `eof(f)`.

For instance, given a file `test.jl`:

```
1 + 1 

ans * 3

function f(x)
    x ^ x 
end

f(3)

println("Hello, World!")
```

we can in the REPL do

```
julia> open("test.jl") do f
           global ans
           while !eof(f)
               cmd = parse(f)
               println("file> $cmd")
               ans = eval(cmd)
               if ans !== nothing
                   display(ans)
                   println()
               end
           end
       end

file> 1 + 1
2

file> ans * 3
6

file> function f(x) # none, line 3:
    x ^ x
end
f (generic function with 1 method)

file> f(3)
27

file> println("Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
```

which is not quite a REPL but somewhat similar to what you're looking for.